# Memory issue with numpy.copy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a big numpy array `my_array` that I copy into another temporary array `temp_my_array` in order to use it in calculations inside a loop, as following:

```
my_array = [10.1, 20.3, ..., 11.2] # a large numpy array
temp_my_array = np.copy(my_array)

for i in range(200000):
     for item in np.where(my_array> 5): 
           temp_my_array[item] = f(my_array[some other items]) 
     my_array = np.copy(temp_my_array)
```

I have memory error with `np.copy` when `my_array` is so big. Besides, profiling showed that np.copy is the slowest part of my code. Any ideas please?

Comment: I need a deep copy, so that when I change an item in `temp_my_array` it doesn't change the same item in `my_array`.

Comment: Cope the array ONCE (what you did on line 2), that will copy the entire array, i.e. all values, all of which you can change at will.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you were using the values from `my_array` in your function call.

Comment: In the second for loop can't you just do `my_array[item] = f(my_array[item])` and not bother with your temp array? The iterator you've created with `np.where` will not reference the changing `my_array` inside the loop.

Comment: @Lærne Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I need a temp array because in each iteration those calculations depend on the values of the previous iteration.

Comment: Ah with your edit it makes more sense now :)

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Sorry I should have explained my question better!

Comment: In this case, you don't need to copy the *whole* array, just the values that have changed. You could store the result of `np.where()`, still iterate through those values, but then after the loop do `my_array[np_where_inds] = temp_my_array[np_where_inds]`. But this doesn't have a large benefit if *most* the indices are returned from `np.where()`.

Comment: I thought about keeping tracking of where I change items and only change those in the end of each iteration but that would be super complicated.

Comment: It's not that complicated, would simply be `inds = np.where(...); for item in inds: ... my_array[inds] = temp_my_array[inds]`. What % of the indices generally pass the condition? Most the indices? Just a few?

Comment: Fortunately less than 10 percent!

Comment: Then I believe the above is a good solution for you, you would be copying 90% less data.

Comment: Yeah I guess so. Thanks! Please provide your solution as an answer and no one else comes up with another solution, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you only copy the values that actually changed. With your code this is only a slight change:

```
my_array = [10.1, 20.3, ..., 11.2] # a large numpy array
temp_my_array = np.copy(my_array)

for i in range(200000):
    inds = np.where(my_array > 5)
    for item in inds: 
        temp_my_array[item] = f(my_array[some other items]) 
    my_array[inds] = temp_my_array[inds]
```

Otherwise you can vectorize your function, but that might be annoying if `[some other items]` relies on your current index or impossible if it relies on the previous `my_array` result.

Answer (score 1):

Does this sound reasonable? Mass assign to original array without making copies

```
my_array = [10.1, 20.3, ..., 11.2] # a large numpy array

for i in range(200000):
     my_array[np.where(my_array>5)] = f(my_array[some other items]) # Mass assign instead of for-loop
```

You'll need to make sure `f()` returns an array now.

Comment: This is an interesting solution! Is this kind of doing calculations in a vectorised version?

Comment: If `some other items` depend on the prior result of `my_array` then you cannot vectorize in this fashion, so it really depends what the other items are.

Comment: @BehzadJamali Yeah assignment with index-array is vectorized with numpy, so this should be very fast.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Yeah that's true, I assumed that it doesn't because it's "some other items" as in from someplace else.

Comment: I am dependent on the prior value of `my_array` .Is true to say that vectorization will speed up my code by removing the second loop but I still need do `my_array = np.copy(temp_my_array)`?